# How to read files from Python scripts called from anywhere

Tags: python

I am writing a piece of Python code, which requires reading a file from a relative position of the script itself.

This is the folder structure:

```
.
+-- cache
|   +-- ..
|   +-- population.json
+-- src
|   +-- ..
|   +-- script.py
+-- ..
```

I tried something like this:

```
folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath("__file__"))
path = os.path.join(folder, "..{0}cache{1}population.json".format(os.path.sep, os.path.sep))
with open(path) as f:
    population = load(f)
```

The problem is that `folder` is always set to the current folder which I am calling the script from.

So how can I fix it, in order to read the files independently of where I call the script from?

Comment: Your problem is a typo: remove the quotes around `"__file__"` - in addition, the replacement with `path.sep` isn't needed, Python will deal with forward slashes on any OS.

Comment: Have you tried using `__file__` instead of `"__file__"`? The former is a hidden variable that should be always present (and holds the actual location of the file), but from my testing, calling `os.path.realpath()` on the latter just supposes you create a file called `__file__` in the current directory and returns the path that it would have.

Comment: To tack on to @Grismar's comment, `os.path.join(folder, os.pardir, 'cache', 'population.json')` should work as well, given the whole point of `os.path.join()` is to put in the separators

Comment: You can do it compactly with `pathlib.Path`. `path = Path(__file__).absolute().parents[1].joinpath('cache', 'population.json')`

Comment: Can one of you guys write up your comment as an answer so the question doesn't look unanswered. @tdelaney

Comment: I see, I made a mistake for those double quotes. It works when I remove it. Thanks for all the improvements, I eventually used ```pathlib```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are basing the operation off of the *literal string* `"__file__"`, which python assumes to be the name of a file in the current working directory. You want to use `__file__`, the *variable* holding the name of the script.

Its a bit odd to mix `os.path` and hand-crafted paths. But things like `os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(...))` get tedious fast. An alternative is the more compact `pathlib`

```
from path lib import Path
path = Path(__file__).absolute().parents[1].joinpath('cache', 'population.json')
```

But that's just an FYI.